# Are all these 3 graphs correct f(x)=x^2

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

My sir said all these 3 graphs are correct for $f(x)=x^2$ where x belongs to [-1,2].[image]

He said that we just prefer using 1st one.Is that right ?

Comment: Nope. Only first one is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I can *imagine* the way how the graphs $2$ and $3$ *can* be correct - but this requires the marks on the $y$ axis to not be equidistant, and actually to be very precisely tailored to the picture you want to show.

For example, if on $y$ axis the $1/4$ mark was *half-way* through (rather than a *quarter of the way* through) between the $0$ and $1$ marks, then the point $(1/2, 1/4)$ would appear on the straight line on the graph $2$.

Having said all that, unless making up a trick question - why would *anyone* do that? People expect equidistant marks on both $x$ and $y$ axis, and if that is the case, only graph $1$ is correct. Any other setup of the axes (including the case when the scale is logarithmic on one or both axes) needs to be specifically noted under the graph, so that people would know what they are looking at.

Comment: You mean to say to say how do it differentiation kind of .